# Enumeration in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql

When I am using QGIS 2.8.3. I want to use a series of predetermined set of texts, such as 'wood', 'brick','concrete'.

I have created an enumeration file in SQL, I do want to link that my existing file using **Edit Widget Properties**.

This is greyed out unfortunately.

How can I overcome this?

I want to choose **enumeration** this is greyed out, as I have the materials in a Look up table/combo box.

Comment: In the Value Map widget, there's an option to load data from CSV file. Is that what you're trying to do?